# How to Join parts of an imported .3ds model

Tags: modeling, objects

When I imported the file the model was separated

[image]

I tried to join the different parts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> but it doesn't do the trick.

Comment: There isn't any active object of mesh type on your screenshot. Select more than one and try joining once more.

Answer (score 1):

You can join this with <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>> *Object*. Just parent your clothes to body with this so whenever you move your character body your clothes, hair etc move with body.